# What happened to Kazak?

Tags: archer

In the *Archer* episode *Un Chien Tangerine*, Archer and Lana have to recover a K9 agent whom they soon discover is actually a dog.  His name is Kazak, he's an English Mastiff, and he is possibly the greatest character on the show so far.

So what happened to the big guy?  Did he return to the U.S. with Archer and Lana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He's last seen in the desert in that episode, and hasn't appeared (or have been mentioned) since, so we have no idea.

They probably got him back to his home base, where he continued to do marvelous missions and to bark "Lana 3" in Morse code before farting.

Comment: Is he really barking in morse code?  If you can provide evidence of this, it would earn you a bounty of, say, 200 points?

Comment: @WadCheber I swear to God I'll decode it later today. Lana in Morse is "   .-.. .- -. .-   " - and you can see that Lana herself goes "WHAT?!" the same way she yells at Archer when he goes "Lana... Lana.... Lanaaaaa"

Comment: I'm not sure I hear the .-.., but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: @WadCheber short bark is dot, double bark is dash. Damn he really does bark that... and it's "Lana 3", too, so we don't have to sit through that long sequence three times. Thoughtful

Comment: I love the expression on his face when he farts.

Comment: Your Youtube link has gone dead.